# Custom third party API authentication and restful services using django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am basically pretty new in django and learning. I have started learning making APIs and authentications and stuffs like that. But I need some guidance.

So, basically I am supposed to use some third party APIs for logging in which will provide me with the bearer auth token. And by using that token I am supposed to use the other APIs of the provider. If someone can guide me towards some proper tutorial or post which could help me that would be great.

Tried using Django Rest Framework but most of them are for creating new APIs but not for consuming any third party API.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Django's popular third party libraries for authentication and authorization here:

https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/authentication/

https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/authorization/

Comment: I have my api for authentication, how to implement in my project?